# Close a CMD window which opened through MATLAB

Tags: matlab, powershell, cmd

I am running a program which calls powershell via the `system` command multiple times. At the end I end up with many opened windows. I would like either these windows to close after each iteration has been completed or run in the background without opening the command window.

```matlab
  pubPath = 'powershell -inputformat none cd C:some path in my pc &';

  [status,publisher] = system(pubPath);
```

I've tried the `exit` and `exit()` commands at the end of my paths but nothing has worked so far. Any help would be great.

Comment: What is the purpose of calling `system()` here?

Comment: Please explain your code, the output of `system` is unused.

Comment: I do use the output of system in later lines of code not displayed on the example. my main concern is just to get rid of the displayed command windows in my screen since after every loop a new command window is spawn and stays there. Therefore at the end of the loop I end up with 20+ command windows which I need to close manually. I wish to get rid of these command windows after it's command is executed successfully, which happens at the end of every loop. Please let me know if you need farther info. Also I have added more info in the code. Please take a look at the pubPath and subPath.

Comment: There is a lot in your question which is unrelated to your problem, especially all but the first code lines. The core of your problem is, you call powershell via system and a command window remains open. Not using powershell or windows, I can't answer your question, but I will edit it to make it hopefully clear for further readers.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I found a solution to my issue. Execute this command after the loop executes all its instances and all the spawned command windows will be closed. BECAREFUL, you might kill more processes than you want.

```
   system('taskkill /IM cmd.exe')
```